# NativePageTransitions and loading dependencies with Angular in IonicFramework

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've read this article: http://scottbolinger.com/4-ways-to-make-your-ionic-app-feel-native/

I'm trying to run my app with native transitions but I can't seem to get them to work. I've added the library through js:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="NativePageTransitions.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

and this is my app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', [
    'ionic-native-transitions'
])

angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

If I run my app through the browser, I get the following error in the console:
**"Cordova is not defined"**

Which should be fine, since cordova is only loaded through the phone app.

I also added this attribute in my anchor tag:

```
<a class="item item-thumbnail-left" native-transitions href="tipo_credito.html">
    <img src="img/credito.jpg">
    <h2>Tipo de Credito</h2>
    <p>Pantalla de Tipo de Credito</p>
  </a>
```

I need help, I don't get why this is still not working when I run it through an android app.